# Laravel Mutators, Accessors

Tags: laravel, mutators

I've tried to implement mutators into my laravel 5.5. project since it looks like this would be the best way to auto-convert date object but for some reason it's not working. What i try to accomplish is to load a date object from mysql format Y-m-d and convert it to d.m.Y and write date objects with a format of d.m.Y to mysql with the format of Y-m-d. I get constantly errors like "delimiter not found" or "format error" etc.

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d h:i';
protected $dates = [
    'joined',

];

function getJoinedAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['joined']->format('d.m.Y');
}

function setJoinedAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['joined']->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: provide the code of what you have attempted to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sould use Carbon library to convert date.

Like this :

```
 public function getDobAttribute($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('d/m/Y');
    }

    public function setDobAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['dob'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $value)->toDateString();
    }
```